# Why did my question about community-managed product backlogs get close votes?

Tags: support, specific-question

I just [deleted my question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/132310/do-community-managed-product-backlogs-exist) after it received two close votes.

Title of the Question was:

> Do community managed product backlogs exist?

The body of the question was:

> Do community managed Scrum product backlogs exist? If so, what would
>   be an example of a successful community managed product backlog, and
>   what are key factors in it's success? If they don't exist, why, and
>   are there any reason that would make using a community managed Scrum
>   product backlog problematic?

What was wrong with it? Why was it on its way to closure?

Comment: This is the question in question - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/132310/do-community-managed-product-backlogs-exist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting your specific question aside for a moment, two community close votes doesn't *necessarily* mean your question is off-topic: otherwise it wouldn't take five community close votes or action from a moderator to close.

If you see your question attracting close votes and you're pretty sure what you want to know is on-topic for the site, consider modifying your question somewhat to shore up any weak points, or ask [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21) or even here on the meta-discussion site for help improving your question so it'll stay open.

Getting back to your question: in general, questions need to demonstrate the necessity of the unique perspective of programmers to answer. General project management questions [aren't really a fit here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2782/8).

While it wasn't flagged, had it been, I would've checked with [Project Management.SE](http://pm.stackexchange.com) to see if it could be migrated, as I think it'd do quite well there. Even though you deleted the question, consider asking it there anyway.

As an aside, this part is a bit bad for the Stack Exchange format:

> If so, what would be an example of a successful community managed product backlog, and what are key factors in it's success?

Asking for lists of examples, even if that's just one part of the question, tends to be the part answerers focus on because it's easy. Solid PM question otherwise.

Comment: +1 Thanks, I dislike how SE manages CLOSED questions, so I proactively manage questions based on my experiences; also found chat to a waste of time, maybe it's just me. That said, I believe might see the issue now, by 'community' I meant by developers on an OSS project; meaning I'm seeking coders, not PMs, who as a community manage a product backlog. Also, understand your concerns about the 'list of X' issue, though that's why I put 'an example', since otherwise someone might simply say 'yes/no' & the example they're thinking is bad; or at least that was my thought. Any additional thoughts?

Comment: @blunders I think it's probably right on the line of what's on-topic for us: if you'd like to try it, I can undelete the question so you can revise it with your clarifications. Let me know.

Comment: +1 Thanks, I'll pass - I really dislike my questions being closed, especially when there's the chance they may collect downvotes for two days, maybe longer. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As a sidenote, a large number of deleted questions may get you [question banned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-thi):

> **Are deleted questions taken into account too?**
>
> Yes. It's not a problem to have deleted questions. But if a large percentage of your questions are deleted by yourself or the community, then apparently they were not suitable for the site. But meanwhile they might have wasted time from users who read them, or even answered them. Therefore deleted questions might have an effect on the filter, among many other secret factors.
>
> Beware that an account with a high public reputation might very well have many deleted questions, including auto-deleted old low-score questions, all of which are only visible to moderators.

Obviously, you have nothing to worry about, all your questions, even the very few closed ones, are highly up voted - the algorithm may be secret(ish) but I don't think it would be so blatantly naive.